# CSS Select particular match on multiple matcher

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following structure in html that should be dynamic

```
<div class="row"><a href="">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </a></div>
<div class="row"><a href="">
        <h1>2</h1>
    </a></div>
<div class="row"><a href="">
        <h1>3</h1>
    </a></div>
<div class="row"><a href="">
        <h1>4</h1>
    </a></div>
<div class="row"><a href="">
        <h1>5</h1>
    </a></div>
```

I want to select with css the `n` match that results of using `.row a h1`. By example I want select the third match that results of using `.row a h1` selector.

I've been trying using `.row a h1:nth-child(3)` but this not works. How I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost right. You should do like this .row:nth-child(3) a h1. It will select third ".row" and find there "a h1"

Comment: Oh!! was very obvious! Thanks!